# Magento not saving product edits and redirects to dashboard?

Tags: javascript, magento

When I try to edit an existing product on Magento, After hitting "Save and continue edit" button , It does not save anything at all and just goes to admin dashboard . 
So I checked the "Network" tab in inspect element of Chrome browser and saw this error :

[image]

Here is the highlighted file (prototype.js) lines containing 1739 :

```
    try {
  var response = new Ajax.Response(this);
  if (this.options.onCreate) this.options.onCreate(response);
  Ajax.Responders.dispatch('onCreate', this, response);

  this.transport.open(this.method.toUpperCase(), this.url,
    this.options.asynchronous);

  if (this.options.asynchronous) this.respondToReadyState.bind(this).defer(1);

  this.transport.onreadystatechange = this.onStateChange.bind(this);
  this.setRequestHeaders();

  this.body = this.method == 'post' ? (this.options.postBody || params) : null;
/* line 1739 */  this.transport.send(this.body);

  /* Force Firefox to handle ready state 4 for synchronous requests */
  if (!this.options.asynchronous && this.transport.overrideMimeType)
    this.onStateChange();

}
```

So how can I fix this problem ? What's wrong with this ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. The problem was in mod_secure. Changes in .htaccess don't help for me, I disabled it from cpanel for the domain and the problem was gone.

Please note, the issue appears only when the website works under https and when I use single HTML tags like  in content (static block, cms pages, product attributes).

For more information please look here http://maxrice.com/magento-fixing-please-wait-error-adding-editing-products-categories/

Answer (score 0):

The above image hints, that the issue is not directly code related forsay, but asset related. The fact that a simple css file is missing, and you have other network related errors before hand.  It appears that prototype is not loading above which when referencing a function that library doesn't exist would cause a problem.. When did this start happening?

Comment: I think it started right after upgrading magento itself and some extensions to the newest version.

Comment: Is this your production environment?

Comment: What you mean by production environment ? @Rob

Comment: As in this website public, not on your local computer.    Can you view page source and post the contents of <head>.  I'd like to see the assets being requested.